# Как начать работать с npm и babel?

Tags: javascript, npm, babel

Привет. У меня возникла проблема. Я пишу код по-старинке - подключаюсь по sftp к своему серверу посредством WinSCP, редактирую файлы при помощи Notepad++. В самом JS подключаю файлы посредством `<script src="some/path/script.js"></script>`. И совсем недавно я познакомился со стандартом ES6(ES2015), и начал активно использовать стрелочные функции. Работаю я в Chrome и для меня мои скрипты работают нормально, но вот в Internet Explorer, стандартном браузере Android(и, как я подозреваю, ещё во многих браузерах) мои стрелочные функции и иже с ними не работают. Просто потому, что браузер их не поддерживает. И вот я начал гуглить, что мне нужно для решения моей проблемы. Ответ состоял из одного слова - Babel. Я узнал, что Babel производит транспиляцию кода из ES6 в ES5. Но как мне его использовать в уже существующей архитектуре проекта, которую я описал выше? У Babel есть много зависимостей, таких как Node.js и npm, которые я ранее никогда не использовал. Как мне влиться в это всё "правильно", не сломав при этом весь свой проект. Есть ли где-то полный гайд по началу работы с nmp и Babel на сервере с Linux(в моём случае Ubuntu 16.04). А то все видео-уроки построены на Windows и cmd, а мне бы терминал. Спасибо.

Comment: Вот вообще-то бабелю вообще не важно, винда там или линукс. А по теме - переделай всё подключение скриптов полностью.

Comment: @Qwertiy уже переписываю согласно [видео-урока](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1ygZZJWvmYQ&t=203s)

Comment: Лучше gulp настрой.

Comment: @Qwertiy а это что?